# A diophantine equation of the form $a^3+b^3+c^3= a\cdot 10^{y+z} +b\cdot 10^z+c\dots$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ be $x$ digit number, $b$ be $y$ digit number  and $c$ be a $z$ digit number. Now we have a diophantine equation of the form 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3= a\cdot 10^{y+z} +b\cdot 10^z+c\dots$$
What is the general solution of the above diophantine equation in natural numbers. Or more generally for any integers.
So far it has been observed that it works for when a,b,c have some number of digits  and works for $a=16666666...$ up to $n$ terms, $b=50000000...$ up to $n$ terms $c=3333333...$ up to $n+1$ terms....

Comment: It is true for 1, 5,3 , like wise 16,50,33 , or 166,500,333 and so on so forth. But the question are these the only solution.

Comment: So you mean, essentially: when does $a^3+b^3+c^3$ coincide with the number we get by concatenating the decimal representations of $a,b$ and $c$, right?

Comment: Yes concatenation.

Comment: No one has tried yet.

Comment: Please I got somewhere it works for (1,5,3), (16, 50, 33), (166, 500,333), and so on so forth. But why it is not true for others value ?

Comment: What are the dots on the right supposed to represent?

Comment: Nothing. It is insignificant.